# Google cloud platform: Add new interface to existing instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

On the edit page of an instance, the "Add Item" button under network interfaces is in the disabled state. Since the button is visible, I guess this operation should be allowed in some way. Is it correct? How can I add a new interface to an existing instance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way to add additional network interfaces after the instance has been created. This can only be done during instance creation, please take a look at the requirements for [assigning multiple network interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces)